# How do I return "Error" as a string.?

Tags: javascript, function, try-catch

Inside the tryCatch function, im trying to write a try block that returns the result of the provided parse() function and write a catch block that returns "Error" as a string.

Im still learning but can someone help point me in the right direction? Im missing the concept and where my mistakes are.

```
function parse(a) {
  let result = parseInt(a);
  if (!result) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return result;
}

function tryCatch(a) {
  try {
    addlert("Welcome guest!");
  } catch (error) {
    display = ("Error");
  }
}
```

Comment: `returns "Error" as a string`  so you want the catch block to `return "Error";`?

Comment: Yeah, thats the goal

Comment: that's the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
function parse(a) {
  let result = parseInt(a);
  if (!result) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  return result;
}

function tryCatch(a) {
  try {
    return parse(a);   // return the parse result here
  } catch (error) {
    return "Error";    // in case of error, return just a string
  }
}

// Pass
console.log( tryCatch('10') );

// Fail
console.log( tryCatch() );
```

Comment: When I run it I get this message:                                                   
   prog.js:18:0 ReferenceError: console is not defined

Comment: Thank you! I got it